# Xamarin.Forms.CollectionView shows different size then what I set when ItemsLayout is GridItemsLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image: Screenshot]

Only items in first row shows different size then other items. However I set same size to all items in XAML. It only happens on Android.

```
    <CollectionView
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HeightRequest="100"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        SelectionMode="Single">

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout
                Orientation="Vertical"
                Span="4"
                HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
                VerticalItemSpacing="10"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image
                        WidthRequest="50"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Source="{local:ImageResource CollectionView.Image.png}"/>
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

[Github](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/64601487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download your sample to test, I can not run your sample, I create new project and upload one sample, you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/collectionsample1

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I downloaded your sample and It works fine first when `Image.HeightRequest` is 50, but when I  change `Image.HeightRequest` to 60, It appears again.

Comment: @ibocon Yes, I can reproduce your problem, If I delete `HorizontalItemSpacing="10"` and `VerticalItemSpacing="10"`, no this problem, I also find [thread1](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8274) and [thread2](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12332), I will report this problem for Microsoft Team, please wait update.

Comment: this [Thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/10624) will solve the bug in future.